# AWS IAM: Allow EC2 instance to stop itself

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm trying to allow all EC2 instances in our AWS account to stop themselves (using an automated script that uses the aws cli). I try to do so by creating an AWS IAM role with the propper policy. However, I can't find how to define the policy to only Allow instances to stop itself (and not other instances).

I tried with the following policy

```
{
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
         {
             "Effect": "Allow",
             "Action": [
                 "ec2:StopInstances"
             ],
             "Resource": [
                 "${ec2:SourceInstanceARN}"
             ]
         }
     ]
}
```

But on validation, this gives me the error `This policy contains the following error: The following resources are invalid : ${ec2:SourceInstanceARN}`

Is there a way to allow an instance to stop itself (and only itself)? If so, how should I do it?

Comment: Any reason you can't just use the OS's shutdown command in your script, instead of using the AWS CLI?

Comment: Ah, of course, how could I forget! Please post this as an answer, then I'll accept it. For me, this would definitely work. However, I can think of two reasons why other people wouldn't want to use shutdown. 

1. shutdown can only be executed with root permission so you need sudo right to be able to do so.

2. If the shutdown behavior of the instance would be terminate, you'll lose the instance rather than stopping it.

Comment: `ec2:SourceInstanceARN` key cannot be used as a variable to populate the ARN for the Resource element in a statement. See notes for [ec2:SourceInstanceARN condition key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policy-structure.html#amazon-ec2-keyss)

Comment: News: AWS just broke the OS's shutdown command. It no longer does what it used to. Neither of the options are useful.

Comment: The correct answer is @OleksandrShmyrko 's one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77121877/238074

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mark B suggested in the comments, I solved my problem by changing my script to use `shutdown` rather than `aws ec2 stop-instances`. This makes the use of any policy needless, as any system can execute shutdown on itself (and only itself).

Comment: Note that AWS has secretly broken this "shutdown" behavior. Now, only two possible outcomes are: 1) halt the instance (not running OS, AWS keeps charging) or 2) terminate instance (that is destroy, delete, gone). The default is 1.

Comment: @KevinBuchs What is you're instance's shutdown behavior set to? Setting it to "stop" should still allow the instance to be stopped when you call the OS's shutdown command acording to the AWS docs. Note you have to use `shutdown` command though and not `halt`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingInstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior

Comment: Set to Stop. This behavior is a change just in the last week

Comment: @KevinBuchs Then please check you didn't enable stop protection or some other settings on your EC2 instance that might intervene with standard stop behavior. I just tried it with and without hibernation enabled, and both instances still stopped in the AWS console when I issues the `shutdown` command from the CLI at the OS level (running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a t3.micro).

Comment: I don't have stop prevention... or terminate prevention enabled. AWS has reproduced the problem so the is no need for further debate.

Answer (score 7):

Shutdown behavior solves the problem with termination but there might be other scenarios that require limited access to API requests (i.e. self tagging). So here's a solution with IAM policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ARN": "${ec2:SourceInstanceARN}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access-analyzer-reference-policy-checks.html#access-analyzer-reference-policy-checks-error-unsupported-global-condition-key

Comment: Has anyone found a replacement solution? "aws:ARN" is not supported anymore.

Comment: @FlorinAndrei You should be able to replace `aws:ARN` with `aws:SourceArn`

Comment: Neither `aws:SourceArn` nor `aws:PrincipalArn` works. But `aws:ARN` works well even though the visual editor complains it's not supported anymore.

Comment: aws:ARN is no longer accepted in the JSON editor of the Console.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aws:userid` and `ec2:InstanceID` in the condition element:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["ec2:StopInstances"],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:userid": "*:${ec2:InstanceID}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This policy gives permissions to shut down any EC2 in testing.

Comment: Added a condition that should limit actions to the instance itself.

Comment: Yes, very nice. Thank you!